# How to insert Joomla! core modules after a basic install?

Tags: joomla-3.x

I wanted to have a fresh 3.5 install for an old site. I installed the `basic install`, transfered all my data and then I realized that some modules I wanted were missing. Like `Who's online` for example. Please tell me there is a way to get them without re-doing everything.
Regards

Comment: You can always create new module from those which are **installed**, either by Joomla or by yourself. By clicking New Module button in Module Manager, you can always see the list of modules which are installed so you can create a new copy of them.

Comment: Yes, you're right ! How stupid I am ! Many thanks for your help Mikan, I was panicked !

Comment: You're welcome. We all face similar brain farts at some point... ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always create a new module from those which are installed, either by Joomla or by yourself.

By clicking the green New Module button in Module Manager, you can always see the list of modules which are installed, so you can create a new copy of the module you want.